# What's the best way to stop a recursive callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an element shake, here is the code, with the jquery library 'jquery.transit'.

```
var s = $('myele');
var randomTran = function(){
    var rh = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
        rv = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
    s.transit({x:rh,y:rv},50,randomTran)
    }
```

The problem is the element will shake constantly, I need to put some stop sign to the recursive callback. What I can think of is to set a variable outside the function as a flag.

```
var s = $('myele');
var flag = 0;
var randomTran = function(){
    if (flag<6) {
        var rh = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
        rv = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
        s.transit({x:rh,y:rv},50,randomTran)
    };
    flag++;
    }
```

But with this I smell the stench of global variable. So question 1 is there better way to do this?
Question 2: Is there any plugin that can make element shake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same thing without a global:

```
var randomTran = function(flag){
  flag = flag || 0;
  if (flag<6) {
    var rh = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
        rv = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
    s.transit({x:rh,y:rv},50,randomTran.bind(this, ++flag))
  };
}
```

With the exception of `s`, this does not rely on any external variables and, as written, does not require you to modify any other code.

Comment: You are right, using the number of shakes left as a parameter is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you! Is `flag ||= 0?` a typo? And, your answer indicates my naming the element as variable `s` is not a good practice, if so, what should I do?

Comment: Sorry, that trailing `?` should have been a `;`

Comment: Made that line more obvious

Comment: Well, in general, single character variable names are not great practice. However, my point was that this function is tied to `s` so that, as written, it can't really be reused. That's not a huge problem... Just an observation.

Comment: No... I'm using `||` to shortcut the value of `flag` to zero if it is undefined (or otherwise falsy). A single `|` is a bitwise operation and would do nothing if one of the operands is 0

Comment: Whoops. I used the postfix increment instead of prefix. Updated.

Comment: Wow it works this time. But I don't understand why the difference between postfix and prefix would be the differentiater in this case?

Comment: You should read up on how those operators work. Or post a new stack overflow question.

Comment: Thank you. I see now, with flag++, the passed parameter will always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it global? You can simply attach it to the `s` object.

```
var s = $('myele');
s.shakesLeft = 10;

var randomTran = function() {
    if (s.shakesLeft--) {
        var rh = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
            rv = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
        s.transit({x:rh,y:rv},50,randomTran)
    }
}
```